# Passing Env Variables to Batch File

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, environment-variables

I'm having difficulties passing a env var (declared in my `.bash_profile`) to a batch file script which executes a BTEQ operation (in Teradata).

.bash_profile contains:

```
export DBPASSWORD='password'
```

BATCH file contains:

```
bteq < bteq_execution_test.sql > bteq_execution_test.log 2>&1 ${DBPASSWORD}
```

I checked that `${DBPASSWORD}` was, in fact, getting passed into the file - but it is NOT being properly accepted as the password in the BTEQ script which looks something like this (the log on portion is where there is an error):

```
.logon mydb/username,$4;
```

Note: I'm referencing the `${DBPASSWORD}` env var set password by position.  Please let me know if anyone could lend a hand.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: @ClassStacker: The order is not important in most shells – `< input cmd > output arg1 arg2` works just as well as `cmd arg1 arg2 < input > output`.

Comment: On second look. There's no `$4` here. `bash` treats redirections by itself, they will not be visible to a script. If `bteq` is a script then it will see the `DBPASSWORD` parameter as `$1` regardless of whether it is placed before or after the redirections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out and it's a solution that will work generally regardless of the actual command to be run in the terminal.  The way I did this was to create a "setup" batch file which runs a bunch of "echo" commands and writes them out to a second file to be executed by BTEQ (in my example).  Here's how I solved it (please refer to the context in my original post):

bteq_execution_test_setup.bat:

```
rm bteq_execution_test_setup1.bat
echo '.LOGON mydb/username,' ${DBPASSWORD} ';' > bteq_execution_test_setup1.bat
echo 'insert into mydb.mytable select top 10 feature1, feature2 from mydb.another_table;' >> bteq_execution_test_setup1.bat
echo '.LOGOFF;' >> bteq_execution_test_setup1.bat
echo '.EXIT;' >> bteq_execution_test_setup1.bat
bteq < bteq_execution_test_setup1.bat > bteq_execution_test_setup1.log 2>&1
```

Then simply executing the command:

```
./bteq_execution_test_setup.bat
```

will execute the command (BTEQ in this case) WITH the desired env var declared in your .bash_profile (or .bashrc, .profile, etc).  Hope this helps someone, I saw a LOT of people asking about this on the Teradata forums!